# Ubuntu Server, How to read information after entering a command

Tags: command-line, pager

How can I pause when I enter a command so that I can read the output, the way `man [command]` does?

For example if I enter

```
samba-tool drs showrepl
```

I can't read all the information at the beginning because the output is too long to fit on the page.

[image: adding ADC samba, virtualbox]

Comment: Use `| more` or `| less` ([also see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81129/what-are-the-differences-between-most-more-and-less)).

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for what is called a *pager*. `less` is one prominent example of a pager. Try

```
samba-tool drs showrepl | less
```

When done, simply press `q` (as in `quit`).